# Linkedin-api This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs

Tags: django, django-allauth, linkedin-api

I am using allauth for django to authenticate with linkedin, but when I am trying to authenticate it is returning in api response that "This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs"
below are my settings for django app.

```
'SCOPE': [
            'w_share','r_emailaddress','r_basicprofile','rw_company_admin'
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first-name',
            'last-name',
            'email-address',
            'picture-url',
            'public-profile-url',
        ]
```

please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Antwane replace

```
access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
```

with

```
access_token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
```

and replace `r_basicprofile` with `r_liteprofile` in scope. In v2 they replace `r_basicprofile` with `r_liteprofile`.

Now to access the basic profile you need to call `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` instead of `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~`. Unlike the v1 API you will not get the Email address in profile API(in short r_liteprofile does not contain Email Address).

While making API request add Header Field `"X-RestLi-Protocol-Version":"2.0.0"`

To access the Email address you should call `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/2086). You may wait until [pull request #2087](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/2087) is merged so [issue #2086](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/2086) is closed, and a new release of django-allauth is published.

Before that, you may create a customized adapter for Linkedin API, with updated access token and authorization URLs. See [allauth documentation](http://LinkedInOAuth2Adapter) for more info.

For example, copy module [`allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2`](https://github.com/eillarra/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/linkedin_oauth2) into your own project and edit `views.py` to update URLs

```
access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
```

need to be changed to:

```
access_token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
```

Now, adding your custom allauth app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` will let you use Linkedin API like before.

Comment: still same issue this resource is no longer available under v1 APIs

Comment: is there anything else which I needs to changes??

Comment: I have followed the step as you have mentioned but it is still not working and give same error.